# LOD parameter link

Tags: game-engine, linked-data

I have an Object with LOD and i use a particule system to spread it on my ground, after applying the particule modifier I get thousands of this object and I want to instanciate them, so that when I modify my LOD setting it applies to all objects. I didn't figure out how to do it and need some help.